# onclick triggering submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, submit

I am relatively green to javascript, but right now I have a form that can be altered by clicking on `<button>`  then at the end they should be able to click a submit button to actually submit and save the form.

All of the other buttons trigger their respective javascript functions just fine, but this one button when pressed should alter the innerHTML of a specific `<span id='planname'>` tag.

```
<td><span id=''></span><span id='planname'></span></td>
<td id='planopt'><button class='button square blue effect-2' onclick="changePlan('Myfixworked','change');">Change</button></td>
```

The problem is when I click on this button, it does run the function:

```
function changePlan(x,action){
    if(action == 'change'){
        var id = 'planname';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

And it changes the innerHTML of that id but immediately after, it submits the form. I tried renaming the id and it produces the same result. I even tried changing the function it triggers and it produces the same result. If I change the id it affects to any id that occurs after this one such as `var id = 'planopt';` , it works great, changes the innerHTML and does not submit the form.

Any help would be appreciated. A Comprehensive code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
function changePlan(x,action){
    if(action == 'change'){
        var id = 'nameofplan';
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = x;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action='' method='post' name='quote'>
    <table border='0' style='border-collapse:collapse;' width='100%' id='serviceplan'>
        <tr style='border-bottom: 2px solid #3D3D3D;'><th align='left' colspan='2'>Description</th><th align='left' width='30%'>Quantity</th><th width='10%'>Price</th><th align='right' width='25%'>Total</th></tr>
        <tr style='border-bottom: 1px solid #3D3D3D;'><td class='subt' colspan='5'>Service Plan</td></tr>
        <tr style='border-bottom: 1px dotted #3D3D3D;'>
            <td align='left'><span id='nameofplan'>Your Plan</span></td>
            <td id='planopt'><button class='button square blue effect-2' onclick="changePlan('Your New Plan','change');">Change</button></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td align='center'>$<span id='planprice'>1.00</span>/month</td>
            <td align='right'>$<span id='subplan'>1.00</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a `type='button'` attribute to your button element. By default, a button element in a form element acts as a submit button.

Using `return false` or `preventdefault` is the wrong approach, since you are merely suppressing the symptoms of the problem (which is that your button is a submit button).

Comment: it's a `button` already. It should be `<input type="button" />` then. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Maybe you're not aware of the `type` attribute on buttons. If a button's type is not specified as `button`, in some browsers it will by default submit the form it is in.

Comment: This is it! The button will be a submit by default. Test http://jsbin.com/ijoqaj/1/edit

Comment: `<button type="button" />`? I know HTML has quirks but I don't believe anyone in their right mind would design a language with this in it :P If it's in the spec can you find it?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen It is pretty silly, but it serves to distinguish from `<button type="submit" />`(default in forms) and `<button type="reset" />`

Comment: Thank you very much! I have not worked with `<button>` very much (obviously). I use inputs most of the time but found some good code for interactive buttons I wanted to use. I appreciate the help!!

Comment: it definitely helped. Sorry, new to being a stackoverflow user too.

Comment: interesting info! came here for just the same problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

Capture the event and cancel the default action.

```
onclick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

You can also `return false;` at the end of the function, but if any errors occur it will *not* cancel the default action.

Comment: This is like making a table out of divs styled `display:table-*`. Instead of suppressing the submit action, don't use a submit button in the first place.

Comment: Why would you say that? Some default behavior of native elements is desirable. Having a `sumbit` button in forms is handy so pressing the `[enter]` key works (for example), while you can still have the form submit it's data via AJAX. Or having a link that performs some JavaScript instead will need to cancel the default action of the click as well.

Comment: Sure, having a submit button is handy when you want a submit button. In this case the OP wants the opposite, a *non-submit* button, so I don't see the point of using a button that submits and patching it to behave like a non-submit button.

Comment: There are other ways to achieve this. I'd argue that `<form>` is misplaced. Neither should he be using `innerHTML` or inline JavaScript calls in HTML. OP is clearly a novice, I hope my suggestion at least broadens his understanding of events so that he may learn to use them more effectively.